# websocket - decode arraybuffer wired characters - nodejs

Tags: node.js, websocket, arraybuffer, ws

I'm connecting to a websocket from my nodejs server using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) package.

And i'm trying to decode the data/arraybuffer i'm receiving. But when i try decode the data/arraybuffer it logs wired characters and was hoping maybe someone could tell me why?

I'm using `TextDecoder` to decode the `arraybuffer`.

```
const ab2str = (buf) => {
  return new TextDecoder().decode(buf);
};
```

The log output.

```
��G����Ԋ{��G�VC�B�
```

My onmessage.

```
client.onmessage = (event) => {
  try {
    //console.log("message:", event.data); 
    console.log(ab2str(event.data));

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("onmessage error:", error.message);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, your message is binary?
If not, then I am using pure `message.toString()` method and didn't have any problems:

```
ws.on('message', (mes, isBinary) => {
   const m = isBinary ? mes : mes.toString();
   if (isBinary) {
       console.log('MESSAGE IS BINARY');
       // you have to deserialize it (e.g. bson)
   } else {
       console.log('RECEIVED MESSAGE: ', m)
})
```